How to resolve EPERM: operation not permitted in turborepo using bun, typescript and tsup
Right now i have a turborepo with only 1 app (hono + bun) and 3 packages (typescript configs, eslint-configs and my custom database package).
For compiling .ts files in my database package I've chosen tsup.
That's tsconfigs that are being used in this package:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}

{
  "extends": "@dekada/typescript-config/node.json",
  "include": ["."],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}

That's my tsup config:
import { defineConfig, type Options } from "tsup";

export default defineConfig((options: Options) => ({
  entryPoints: ["src/index.ts"],
  clean: true,
  dts: true,
  format: ["cjs"],
  target: "esnext",
  ...options,
}));

And that's my package.json of my database package:
{
  "name": "@dekada/database",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@dekada/typescript-config": "*",
    "@types/bun": "latest",
    "tsup": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup",
    "dev": "tsup --watch"
  },
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
}

turbo.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
  "globalDependencies": ["**/.env.*local"],
  "tasks": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"]
    },
    "lint": {
      "dependsOn": ["^lint"]
    },
    "dev": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "cache": false,
      "persistent": true
    },
    "start": {
      "dependsOn": ["^start"],
      "persistent": true
    }
  }
}

When i cd in this package and run build or dev directly, everything works fine, it watches changes and recompiles code.
But, when I run turbo dev:
Everything starts fine, firstly It builds my package and hono app starts with no errors, but when i make changes to src .ts files in my package, tsup throws an error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'U:\dekada\packages\database\dist\index.js'. When i try to open same file after error in vscode, I get same issue. When I exit proccess, file just disappears.
My versions:

Windows 11 23H2 22631.353
Bun 1.1.12
turbo latest

